# how to do "isatpty()" in Python, similar to isatty()

Tags: python

I can use `os.isatty(sys.stdout)` to tell if I my output is going to a terminal.

But suppose I `pty.fork()` a child, then inside the child process `os.isatty(sys.stdout)` returns True regardless where the parent is going.

How can I tell, inside the child process, that `sys.stdout` is not going to a real tty?

Comment: This is unlikely what you want. Most tty devices these days are pseudo terminals. Unless you're using a terminal connected by a serial cable or the character mode console you're not using a "real" tty. If you're using a terminal window under X (eg. xterm or GNOME Terminal) or logged in remotely (eg. using ssh), then you're using a pseudo tty.